# If $f$ is integrable in $[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ and $f(x)≥0$ except for a value $c$ such that $f(c)=-1$. Show that the integral of  is positive.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Given $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ where $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]-\lbrace c\rbrace $ and $c \in (a,b) $ such that $f(c)=-1$. Prove that if $f$ is integrable in $[a,b]$ then $ \int_{a}^{b} f(x)  dx \geq 0$ .

It has to be solved with Riemann-integration and it just says that $f$ is integrable.

The thing is that I don't really know how to work with the removable discontinuity in c, even if the function is integrable.

Comment: Could you please tell us a bit more about your background? What integral have you studied, Riemann? Lebesgue? Also, we need to know more about the function $f$. Is it continuous except at $c$ ?

Comment: Oh, sure. It has to be solved with Riemann-integration and the problem just says that $f$ is integrable and positive except for c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon \in (0, \min(c-a, b-c))$, so that $P_\varepsilon = \{a < c-\varepsilon < c+\varepsilon < b\}$ gives a partition of $[a,b]$.

Then the corresponding lower Riemann sum $L(P_\varepsilon, f)$ satisfies
$$\begin{align*}\int_a^bf(x)\,dx &\geq L(P_\varepsilon, f) \\ &= (c-\varepsilon-a)\inf f([a,c-\varepsilon])+2\varepsilon\inf f([c-\varepsilon, c+\varepsilon]) + (b-c-\varepsilon)\inf f([c+\varepsilon, b]) \\ &\geq (c-\varepsilon-a)(0) + 2\varepsilon(-1)+(b-c-\varepsilon)(0) \\ &= -2\varepsilon.\end{align*}$$

That is, $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \geq -2\varepsilon$.

Let $\varepsilon \to 0$ to see $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, and hence on every sub interval of it, you can write the integral on $[a,b]$ as the limit as $\epsilon$ goes to zero of $\int_a^{c-\epsilon}f(x)dx+\int_{c+\epsilon}^b f(x) dx$ Now, let $m$ and $n$ be the infimum of $f$ in both these intervals (and hence real positive numbers, or zero). Then, $\int_a^{c-\epsilon}f(x)dx+\int_{c+\epsilon}^b f(x) dx \geq m(c-a-\epsilon)+n(b-c-\epsilon)$. In the limit as $\epsilon$ goes to zero, $\int_a^b f(x)dx \geq m(c-a)+n(b-c)\geq0$

Comment: "you can write the integral on $[a,b]$ as the limit as $\epsilon$ goes to zero of [...]" feels like begging the question to me.  I would assume OP needs to work on the level of lower Riemann sums and partitions.

Comment: @BrianMoehring really? It seems to me that it follows straight from the additivity of Riemann integration. Also, I'm not quite sure how to solve this question with lower Riemann sums, so maybe some other folk can provide an answer with that approach